# Rails simple_form association select with create option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-forms, simple-form

I have a form with a belongs_to assocation, and I'd like the user to be able to either select from their addresses, or create a new one. It breaks when the form has validation errors because of conflicting information in the parameters, i.e.

```
"transaction" => { "address_id" = "25", 
    "address_attributes" => { "id" => "25" } }
```

I've simplified relevant files:

Transaction.rb

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end
```

Transaction#new view

```
<%= simple_form_for @transaction do |f| %>

  <%= f.association :address, :collection => current_user.addresses,
    :include_blank => "Enter new address",
    :value_method => :id %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
    <%= address_fields.input :line1 %>
    <%= address_fields.input :line2 %>
    <%= address_fields.input :city %>
    <%= address_fields.input :state %>
    <%= address_fields.input :zip, :label => "Zip / Post Code" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Confirm" %>

<% end %>
```

Transaction#create controller

```
def create
  trans_params = {}
  if params[:transaction][:address_id].blank? && !params[:transaction][:address_attributes].nil?
    trans_params[:address_attributes] = params[:transaction][:address_attributes]
  elsif !params[:transaction][:address_id].nil?
    trans_params[:address_id] = params[:transaction][:address_id]
  end

  @transaction = Transaction.new(trans_params)
end
```

Of course there is a chunk of code missing but I think these are the only relevant sections. The problem I'm having is, when you submit the form and there is validation errors, simple_form automatically adds `<input id="transaction_address_attributes_id" name="transaction[address_attributes][id]" type="hidden" value="25">` to the end of my form, causing the parameters to clash and giving the error:

```
Couldn't find Address with ID=25 for Transaction with ID=
```

I imagine there is a much better way of dealing with the params in the controller. Any ideas? I have considered using javascript to remove and re-render the "address attributes" form but I'd rather not rely on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have written [guide to doing nested model forms in rails](http://www.dixis.com/?p=561), where I solve the create or select problem.

However your problem is related to your controller. Without the code it is hard to tell, but afaik what seems to happen is that in the creation, something goes wrong (the validation error), the address is saved and so the ID is stored in the `Transaction`, but because the validation failed, the address-creation is rolled back, but the ID still remains in your (unsaved) transaction giving you the error you observe.

Before rendering new again, you could just set the `address_id` to nil, but that would depend whether a new address was created or an existing address was selected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does cocoon have a fallback with javascript disabled?

Comment: I tried it out but having a few issues with it... e.g. if a field in the nested association fails validation, it disappears when the page reloads.

Comment: Please post an issue on github, so I can investigate it further.